# Email not working with ci 3.0 app

Tags: php, codeigniter, email, openshift

I was using ci 2.2 with smtp email, and as usual it was working and is currently working fine, but when I upgraded my app to ci 3.0, it is giving me error:

`Failed to authenticate password. Error: 535 Authentication Failed
Unable to send email using PHP SMTP. Your server might not be configured to send mail using this method.`

Now here is the code I'm using `ci app 2.2 email code'`:

```
function sendEmail($to,$subject,$body,$from = "Do not reply")
{
    $CI =& get_instance();
    $CI->load->library('email');
    $config['protocol']     = 'smtp';
    $config['smtp_host']    = 'ssl://smtp.myserviceprovider.com';
    $config['smtp_port']    = '465';
    $config['smtp_timeout'] = '7';
    $config['smtp_user']    = 'email@myemail.com';
    $config['smtp_pass']    = 'email_password';
    $config['charset']      = 'utf-8';
    $config['newline']      = "\r\n";
    $config['mailtype']     = 'html'; // or html
    $config['validation']   = TRUE; // bool whether to validate email or not
    $CI->email->initialize($config);
    $CI->email->from('emaily@myemail.com',$from);
    $CI->email->to($to); 
    $CI->email->subject($subject);
    $CI->email->message($body);
    if($CI->email->send())
    {
        return true;
        //echo $CI->email->print_debugger();
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
        //echo $CI->email->print_debugger();
    }
}
```

`//I'm using a custom helper to send email, this is working code`

`//This code is not working with ci 3.0`

```
$config['protocol']     = 'smtp';
$config['smtp_host']    = 'ssl://smtp.myserviceprovider.com';
$config['smtp_port']    = '465';
$config['smtp_timeout'] = '7';
$config['smtp_user']    = 'email@myemail.com';
$config['smtp_pass']    = 'email_password';
$config['charset']      = 'utf-8';
$config['newline']      = "\r\n";
$config['mailtype']     = 'html'; // or html
$config['validation']   = TRUE; // bool whether to validate email or not
$this->email->initialize($config);
$this->email->from('email@myemail.com','FirstName LastName');
$this->email->to('to@too.com'); 
$this->email->subject(rand(1000,9999));
$this->email->message('body of email');
if($this->email->send())
{
    echo $this->email->print_debugger();
}
else
{
    echo $this->email->print_debugger();
}
```

`This code is not working. I don't know why, using ci 3.0`. Is there something I'm missing, because if the code is working with ci 2.2 without problem, it should be working with other part too.

Comment: What server you on for testing Lamp, wamp, xammp. You will need to setup send mail on server end also. Here is a tutorial on how to set up sendmail on xammp and wamp https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TO7MfDcM-Ho

Comment: this is code for live server

Comment: why are you using smtp host and other setting to send email.Let you server handlle  it .

Comment: yes using smpt, how do let server handle that? please explain